# Traditional login page giving access to AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, authentication, redirect, nginx, flask

I'm starting a simple web application with [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) for the API and [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) for the frontend, all served by Nginx. The api is located on `http://site/api/`, and obviously all endpoints are properly secured.

I'm exploring my options regarding authentication and I stumbled upon [this page](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/), in which the author states the following in his introduction:

> One option I tried out was to **have a traditional login page which, on success, redirects to a secured URL which loads the actual application. This has the added benefit that the client side code and view templates used for pages intended for logged in users are not accessible to anyone not logged in.** [...] I wanted a seamless user experience with no full page reloads beyond the initial page load, so I decided to play around a little and see if I could come up with an alternative.

The author then proceeds in detailing the alternative, while I would be interested by **implementing the original solution** (tradition login page which redirects to a secured URL). I have tried several things, such as using Nginx [`X-Accel-Redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel) upon successful authentication, but failed to reach a fully satisfactory solution.

**So there's the question:** how I can implement a traditional login page which, on success, redirects to a secured URL containing my AngularJS application? For the moment, my login endpoint stands on `http://site/api/login`, and static data (including the Angular app) are served by nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible solutions:

1) Serve everything with Flask (login page and static files for the application) in a separate Blueprint. Authenticate with something like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

2) If you want better performance, you can [use Lua scripting in Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#access_by_lua) to implement the authentication for the static resources. You will need to set a cookie in the login page that you can read in Lua. I would only do that if the first solution resulted in performance issues though.

Answer (score 0):

The codes look like 
html:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="container login">
        <h1>User Login</h1>
        <p>Please login below, if you have forgotten your password please <a href="/index.html#/resetpassword"><b>Click Here</b></a> to reset it.</p>
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="inputEmail" required ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" required ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="IsLoginFailure">
                <p><span class="error"><b>Error:</b>Your emailId or password is wrong </span></p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-grove-one btn-lg btn-bold" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        </form>
        <br />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope',  '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', '$route',  function ($scope,  $http, $rootScope, $location, $route) {


$scope.login = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://site/api/login',
                data: $scope.user
            }).success(function (response) {
                    $location.path(Your Path);
                    $route.reload();
                });

            }).error(function () {
                $scope.IsLoginFailure = true;
            })
        }
    }])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't sound like a secured URL to me: anyone can just directly go the AngularJS app url (`YourPath` in your code) and retrieve the html and js without being logged in.